# 16.04 ALSA / Radeon R9 380 HDMI Audio

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, 16.04, hdmi

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 15.10 to 16.04, and audio output from my GPU's HDMI port no longer seems to work at all.

Output from alsa-info.sh can be found here, which includes aplay -l among other useful things. http://pastebin.ca/3584748

Output from the onboard sound card (Card 0) and my USB audio interface (Card 1) seems to work fine. I haven't tried input.

I had been using fglrx/Catalyst, and wonder whether the shift to the open-source drivers (AMDGPU) is the culprit, but I thought I'd ask around here whether anyone knows for sure, or can spot a configuration error. (Hopefully)

And here is relevant output from lspci -vvnn:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1458:a182]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 32
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 139
        Region 0: Memory at dff20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Region 4: Memory at dff00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380] [1002:aad8]
        Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380] [148c:aad8]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 138
        Region 0: Memory at dfe60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

ETA: (4/27) I tried to send sound to the thing directly using `speaker-test -Dhw:3,3 -c2 -r48000` with no success. I also tried the other devices on the card, 7 through 11. Playing directly to the onboard audio device, (`hw:2,0` at the time) of course, worked.

Also noteworthy is the fact that `pavucontrol` indicates that sound is being sent to the device.

ETA: (4/28) I tried booting into two different live images of two different distros to see if I could get a good `alsa-info.sh` output, but the audio didn't work on either of them either. One was Ubuntu 15.10, and I installed fglrx; still no sound. I suppose it could be a physical problem with the card, but it would be an amazing coincidence.

I've seen mentions of the `radeon.audio` module property around. The `radeon` module isn't loaded, `amdgpu` is the relevant module it seems. I haven't been able to set `amdgpu.audio`, (which is a valid property, and seems to do the same as the `radeon` equivalent) but that's another problem I am having in a separate question. (Here: [/etc/modprobe.d/ conf file ignored](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764682/etc-modprobe-d-conf-file-ignored))

ETA: (5/01) I had begun to suspect, and another person has confirmed, ([/etc/modprobe.d/ conf file ignored](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764682/etc-modprobe-d-conf-file-ignored#comment1142297_764682)) that the `amdgpu` driver just isn't capable of supporting audio out for my GPU's chipset. If I find otherwise, I'll update the question again, or answer it.

Comment: Perhaps notably, I did write a bug report since I wasn't the one who broke it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1574863

So if anyone else is having the same issue, there you are

Comment: I have the same graphic card and exactly the same problem. Of course I read about the end of fglrx after updating to 16.04...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just installed [AMDGPU-PRO driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) (current version is 16.30) and the sound now works from my screen using the HDMI cable!

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
```

gives me

```
[AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380]
```

Comment: Works a treat!

Now of course a new problem has cropped up that I think is likely a bug with AMDGPU-PRO, it being in beta. :P If the display is powered off, turning it back on doesn't resume communication between the display and the graphics card. (I have to switch to one of the TTYs and reboot from there)

It's a TV, not a computer monitor, so that might be part of the problem.

Thanks for solving the initial issue!

Comment: I was regularly coming back on launchpad.net but as time passed, I thought there is some new drivers available around. I have also less crash from games on Wine. I always had problems with TVs using HDMI since 14.04...