# /etc/modprobe.d/ conf file ignored

Tags: drivers, modprobe, amd-graphics

I am trying to add a module option for the amdgpu module, but it is seemingly ignored.

`/etc/modprobe.d/amdgpu.conf` contents:

```
options amdgpu audio=1
```

Relevant output from `modprobe -c | grep amdgpu`, indicating that the option is part of the configuration:

```
options amdgpu audio=1
alias pci:v00001002d00006900sv*sd*bc*sc*i* amdgpu
alias pci:v00001002d00006901sv*sd*bc*sc*i* amdgpu
alias pci:v00001002d00006902sv*sd*bc*sc*i* amdgpu
[...]
```

15 lines of output from `systool -vm amdgpu`:

```
Module = "amdgpu"

  Attributes:
    coresize            = "987136"
    initsize            = "0"
    initstate           = "live"
    refcnt              = "4"
    srcversion          = "AC0EDC775DD303A402948D2"
    taint               = ""
    uevent              = <store method only>

  Parameters:
    aspm                = "-1"
    audio               = "-1"
    bapm                = "-1"
    benchmark           = "0"
    deep_color          = "0"
```

As you can see, audio is still set to "-1". Am I doing something wrong?

ETA: Per Steve Roome, the card is a PowerColor PCS+ AXR9 380 4GBD5-PPDHE. (A Radeon R9 380) Output from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16124381/

Comment: I rebooted the system after adding `/etc/modprobe.d/amdgpu.conf`.

Comment: You should be editing radeon.conf See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: I tried that, it didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the model of your video card and add the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log using paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I have looked through the /var/log/Zorg.0.log and I cannot see any attempt to set up the HDMI audio, but it has told me that you have the TONGA chipset. I suspect HDMI audio has not been implemented yet on this chipset. Try googling "DAL Tonga AMDGPU".

Comment: I will Google when I'm home, but HDMI audio must be implemented--it worked with no intervention from myself until I upgraded to 16.04. (I have a question open about that as well) Thanks for looking over the log

Comment: 16.0.4 uses the AMDGPU driver. Previously you were using fglrx.

Comment: I have looked without success for documentation on AMDGPU and its capabilities and shortcomings, but the more information I gather on the HDMI audio issue, the more I think you are right.

Does the lack of support for the TONGA chipset explain why amdgpu.audio is not being set by my configuration in modprobe.d?

Comment: That was my thinking. So you should raise a bug report on Ubuntu. You then have the choice of (1) waiting until the issue is fixed (2) use the fglrx driver (3) patch the kernel

Comment: (2) is not doable.