# Fresh install of 16.04 is lagging and unusable

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics

I have just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04.3 and seem to have an issue with everything being slow to respond / generally lagging. You can first notice is after the grub menu the screen reveals itself by a wipe effect that repeats until the full image is visible. it does this while using the computer as well. I have nomodeset as when i was booting up previously my fans would spin rapidly and i would be greeted with a black screen.

My pc specs are as follows

- Gigabyte hd3-z170 gaming
- i5 3670k
- 16gb ddr4 ram
- radeon r9 380
- samsung ssd 750 evo 500gb

I am also dual booting into windows 10 and it works perfectly normal.

I tried installing admgpu-pro drivers using ./amdgpu-pro-install but it caused my login screen to go into a loop leaving me to uninstall them.

When i used the parameters ./amdgpu-pro-install --compute, it worked but i saw no improvements with the lag.

I believe this is a graphics card issue but im stuck on how to fix it. Has anyone else with a similar issue had any luck?

Comment: If you believe that is a graphics card issue, please check this link [16.04 ALSA / Radeon R9 380 HDMI Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763986/16-04-alsa-radeon-r9-380-hdmi-audio), good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: i believe that is the issue, the r9 380 isnt playing nice with the drivers, going to do a fresh install and attempt to install radeonsi drivers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 ALSA / Radeon R9 380 HDMI Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763986/16-04-alsa-radeon-r9-380-hdmi-audio)